# Drupal 7 View display "Page not found" without contextual filter

Tags: 7, views

I have created a drupal view for my content type "Work", it has a relationship "Taxonomy terms on node" and a contextual filter "(term) Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name". My path is /work/%.

When I go to work/sector, then it displays correctly all from content type work with the vocabulary sector. But when I go to just /work I get a "page not found".

Is there anything I need to be looking out for?

Answer (score 2):

Click on your second argument, under Contextual Filter.

You should see an option - "When the filter value is not in the URL". That's where you specify what to do when the argument, i.e. "/sector" is not present. Provide the appropriate selection, and make sure Show "Page not found" is not selected.
[image]